# Ошибка подключения клиента к серверу

Tags: android, genymotion, eclipse

Здравствуйте.

Пишу клиент и сервер. Клиент пишу в AndroidStudio, сервер написан в Eclipse.
Вроде все сделал верно, сперва пробовал передать сообщение с клиента на сервер, используя эмулятор BlueStacks. Все работало замечательно. Теперь, по причине того, что BlueStacks
не совсем является эмулятором, пришлось перейти на Genymotion.

Код клиента и сервера не изменял, ip = 10.0.2.2, port = 8080.
На сервере порт 8080.

В AndriodStudio в xml прописано:

`< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" / >`

Но из genymotion клиент в упор не видит (не находит) сервер:

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to
> connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8080):
> connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection
> timed out)

В сети куча аналогичных проблем, но решения, для своего случая, я так и не нашел. (

В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В браузере проверь адрес (на эмуляторе), "гена" работает через бридж, виртуальные машины, возможно нет доступа к интернету с эмулятора...

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)